# A cylinder UV mapping

Tags: texturing, uv, scale

Is there a way to make a *uniform solid* UV map of such figure ?
Thanks !

[image]
In red color it's illustrated what I would like to see insted of what I have.

[image: A mesh and a UV unwrap showed in the screenshot above.]

Comment: Could you provide  screenshot of mesh and uv map?

Comment: Sure, it was added.